# Error importing CSV in SQL Server for 1 Specific File All Others Work fine

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, import-csv

I have downloaded files from the website below:
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/nfl-big-data-bowl-2022/data

I've imported games.csv, players.csv, and PFFScoutingData.csv.
However, when I go to import plays.csv using SQL Server's Import & Export Wizard I'm getting errors that I have been trying to resolve by changing data types and I cannot figure it out.

Data Source: Flat File Source
File Name: plays.csv
Locale: English
Unicode: Not Checked
Code Page: 1252 (ANSI - Latin I)
Format: Delimited
Text Qualifier: none
Header row delimiter: CR/LF
Header rows to skip: 0
Column Names in first data row is checked

I then click next and leave everything as default on the new screen.

Destination: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

I then click next, and then next again on the next page.

I click finish twice and then I get this error.

- Executing (Error)
  Messages

  - Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column ""quarter"" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
  - Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - plays_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns["quarter"]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - plays_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns["quarter"]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
  - Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\nflcomp\plays.csv" on data row 3.
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
  - Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - plays_csv returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: SSIS is not very good at guessing metadata. It looks like it has used the default column lengths, which are quite small, even though your data requires longer ones. This might be a case when you need to make an actual SSIS package, and define all the input and output columns, instead of using the wizard.

Comment: For an actual answer, we'd need to see the specific line of the CSV the wizard-generated package is failing on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I show you the line the wizard is failing on?